# Mocking generic repository factory method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I've made refactoring if our repository factory to make it more generic and right now the method creating repositories looks like that:

```
public TRepository CreateRepository<TRepository>(params object[] parameters)
        where TRepository : class
{
    if (_serviceProvider == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(_serviceProvider));

    return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<TRepository>(_serviceProvider, parameters);
}
```

In my production code I am using it like so and it works like charm:

```
_concreteRepo = repoFactory.CreateRepository<ConcreteRepo>();
```

But when I am trying to refactor unit tests as well I am having difficulties setting up the factory, this is how I do it but it doesn't work.

```
public class Tests 
{
    // Since I am using Moq I can't mock anything but abstract types thus having problems with type conversion in set up.
    protected readonly Mock<IConcreteRepository> _concreteRepositoryMock = new Mock<IConcreteRepository>();
    protected readonly Mock<IRepositoryFactory> _factoryMock = new Mock<IRepositoryFactory>();

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        // If I don't cast concreteRepositoryMock compiler complains that cannot convert from abstract to concrete repository.
        // If I cast it fails and returns null.
         _factoryMock.Setup(f => f.CreateRepository<ConcreteRepository>())
            .Returns(_concreteRepositoryMock.Object as ConcreteRepository);
    }
}
```

Any idea how can workaround it? Seems like my `CreateRepository` method is returning concrete types, but mocking I cannot mock my concrete repository.Also I couldn't pass abstract types to `CreateRepository`, because `CreateInstance` requires concrete types.

Comment: Not directly related but the presence of a Factory, a Repository, genericity, a param array and a ServiceProvider in just the first 5 lines of code is probably a sign of over-engineering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found workaround to this which I am relatively happy at the moment, but if any other suggestions appear I would love to hear them.

So problem was that my `CreateRepository` was returning concrete implementation while it had to return abstraction because all my mocks are abstractions (because Moq mocks only abstractions). Therefore I modified my method as follows:

```
TInterface CreateRepository<TRepository, TInterface>(params object[] parameters)
    where TRepository : class, TInterface where TInterface : class;
```

And this guaranteed compile-time safety for my set up method and success afterwards. I do find it somewhat cumbersome, but I can live with it for now.

**NOTE:** You can always do extension method within internal class in your testing assembly and copy&paste the code from production method, this way you won't pollute your production code, however, this can be problematic if someone tries to change the production method without changing the test one, this is why I choose to "pollute" my production code for the sake of safety.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is that you expect the Mock object:

```
protected readonly Mock<IConcreteRepository> _concreteRepositoryMock = new Mock<IConcreteRepository>();
```

To be instance of ConcreteRepository, which is wrong assumption.

```
_concreteRepositoryMock.Object is IConcreteRepository
```

This should say "TRUE" while

```
_concreteRepositoryMock.Object is ConcreteRepository
```

This should say "FALSE".

You have to either switch your PROD code to be happy with abstraction (IConcreteRepository) or mock the final class

```
protected readonly Mock<ConcreteRepository> _concreteRepositoryMock = new Mock<ConcreteRepository>();
```

in your mock (note that mocking concrete classes is usually not easy - you need all mocked methods to be virtual etc.).